# assert JSON response

Tags: python, json, response, assert

i have an python API call, and the server response is coming to me as JSON output.

How can I assert that the "status" from this output is 0 for example:

```
def test_case_connection():
    req = requests.get_simple(url=Server.MY_SERVER, params=my_vars)
    assert req["status"]="0"
```

is what i've tried.

The response is looking like:

```
{"status" : 0, ......}
```

error i got is:

```
TypeError: 'Response' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you simply need to check that the request was successful, using `request.status_code` will do the trick:

```
def test_case_connection():
    req = requests.get_simple(url=Server.MY_SERVER, params=my_vars)
    assert req.status_code == 200
```

If you want instead to check for the presence of a specific key-value pair in the response, you need to convert your response payload from json to a dict:

```
import json

def test_case_connection():
    req = requests.get_simple(url=Server.MY_SERVER, params=my_vars)
    data = json.loads(req.content)
    assert data["status"] == "0"
```

If you are using the Requests library you can avoid converting json manually by using its [builtin json decoder](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content).

Comment: data = json.loads(req.content)
    assert data["status"] == 0
this one did the trick. Thank you so much!!!
I need to check for specific value, since i will have more than 30 of them and each time i need to check for dif, most of wich are totally not successful call

Answer (score 0):

It should be `assert req['status'] == 0`, i. e. comparison (`==`) instead of assignment (`=`) and `0` as integer not `"0"` as string (not entirely sure about the latter).

Comment: assert req['status'] == 0
E       TypeError: 'Response' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: @GeorgeG. right, forgot that you need to extract json first

Answer (score 0):

status code in assertion:

```
response.ok #it is True if response status code is 200.
```

In context with pytest it would be like that:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("fixture_name", [(path, json)], indirect=True)
def test_the_response_status_code_first(fixture_name):
    assert fixture_name.ok, "The message for the case if the status code != 200."
    # the same with checking status code directly:
    assert fixture_name.status_code == 200, "Some text for failure. Optional."
```

Comment: Regarding the JSON, no import required. Python 3. fixture_name.json()[0]["node_name"] == 42